# Настройка интерфейса in-app updates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdk

сейчас внедряю in-app обновления и встал вопрос, можно ли сделать кастомный диалог о наличии обновления, соблюдая свою дизайн-систему?
Или же нужно будет использовать какую-либо библиотеку и скачивать обновленную версию со своего сервера?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.